# How to create intent from onPostExecute() to Tabs

Tags: android, android-intent, tabs

I want to create an Intent from my Asynctask class to a tab.  If I use the following code then instead of showing the data to the same tab a new activity is created and the data are displayed on that activity.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
super.onPostExecute(result);
Intent in = new Intent(context, Details.class);
in.putExtra(TAG_FNAME, firstname);
in.putExtra(TAG_LNAME, lastname);
in.putExtra(TAG_GNDR, gender);
in.putExtra(TAG_DOB, date_of_birth);
context.startActivity(in);
}
```

In the above code i am sending the data from my Asynctask class to my Details.class
the Detail class contains 2 tabs: home and profile

how can i send the data to my profile.class which is a tab in Details.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same way `Details` class will handle the other parameters, then you should handle an additional data in the extra of the bundle.

I guess you use either `onCreate` or `onNewIntent` (better) to handle those parameters in `Details` class. From there, create your tab fragment using your static factory method (look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) for the `newFragment` method), then use your tab manager to display the fragment.

Btw, `Details` is poorly name, `DetailActivity` would be better.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code. i was not not able to understand what you are saying... and thanks i will change the name of my Details class...

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate way of doing this is by Handlers and Message:

You should declare Handler as:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    switch(msg.what){
          case MSG_INTENT:
          // get data from bundle and startActivity() here.;
          Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage() - MSG_00 - msg: "+
                                (String)msg.obj);
          break;
    }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
};
```

And in your onPostExecute(): create a `Message` object and pass the `message.what`to handler.

```
Message msg = new Message();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putExtra("CallingActivity", "Details.class");
b.putExtra(TAG_FNAME, firstname);
b.putExtra(TAG_LNAME, "Details.class");
b.putExtra(TAG_GNDR, lastname);
b.putExtra(TAG_DOB, date_of_birth);
msg.setData(b);
msg.what = MSG_INTENT;
mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

Comment: where should i declare the Handler in my Deatils class or in my Profile class?

Comment: pass the handler to your async task.